# Puppet 4.2 is printing strange error messages and fails on execution

Tags: puppet, archlinux-arm

I am running Puppet 4.2 (both master and client) and since yesterday I started to get strange errors when running `puppet agent -t`.

```
# puppet agent -t
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: execution expired
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': execution expired
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: execution expired
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': execution expired
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: execution expired
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: execution expired
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: execution expired
```

My puppet.conf is pretty simple:

```
[main]
    certname = mastermachine
[agent]
    server = mastermachine
    pluginsync = true
    runinterval = 300
```

I am running Arch Linux-arm if that matters.

Puppet master is up and listening on its specified port (8140). 

And as I mentioned, it worked yesterday.

What has happened?

Comment: That run interval is quite rapid. How many agents are there? Are you using puppetserver? If not, what is the master's stack (Passenger? WEBrick/standalone?) Have you checked the logs on the master? Is there an indication of how long catalog compilation takes on the master side? Have you tried restarting the master service?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (i686 arch):

```
mkdir /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules
```